# Detaching Process from "Run Script Over SSH" in Shortcuts

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, automation

I'm trying to use the "Run Script Over SSH" in Shortcuts (found under `Scripting > Shell`.

I want to execute a long running command from a sharesheet. So that the sharesheet doesn't remain open, and I can move on to other tasks without worrying about leaving the network etc, the command, foo, needs to execute detached from the SSH session.

I have tried using `nohup`, but I receive a `nohup: can't detach from console: Undefined error: 0`. I have also tried backgrouding `&` and using `disown`, but neither technique has been successful. Also tried `screen` on my machine, but it just hangs blank. Are these ineffective because of security changes to MacOS?

What is the appropriate way to keep `foo` running after my ssh session is gone?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tmux` it'll keep sessions alive after you leave.

Answer (score 1):

I use the GNU `screen` for this purpose.

For macOS host,

```
screen -dm zsh -c "your scripts"
```

For linux host,

```
screen -dm bash -c "your scripts"
```

According to GNU `screen` man page,

> ```
>    -d -m   Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it.
>           This is useful for system startup scripts.
> ```

**The side effect** is that the `screen` process may still be alive even after the job is done for some commands if `zombie kr` is in `~/.screenrc`.
You can check it with `ps aux | grep -i screen`.

e.g.

```
screen -dm bash -c "/usr/bin/yt-dlp -q -o '/mnt/drive_name/youtube/%(title.0:60)s.%(ext)s' 'youtube urls'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
screen -S myScreen
/usr/local/bin/myScript "Shortcut Input" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
screen -d myScreen
exit
```

My command needed to be attached to an input and it was not running when it would detach with a regular screen C-a D